# Can S3 Objects be downloaded as Zip from Apache Server?

Tags: python, apache, rest

I want to know if its possible to use a script on a server or through using AWS's API to download a portion of an S3 bucket with the folder structure that the files have as 'prefixes'.

EX:
ParentFolder/Folder1/Test.txt
ParentFolder/Folder2/Test.txt

Is it possible to download the "ParentFolder" and get a download containing (you guessed it) the two folders "Folder1" & "Folder2"?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sure. You can use "cp" on linux or via bash script to copy all files containing a certain prefix:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/prefix/ . --recursive
```